# Elasticsearch watcher and Microsoft Teams webhook

Tags: json, elasticsearch, webhooks, microsoft-teams, elasticsearch-watcher

I have been trying desperately for 5 days to create an elasticsearch watcher alert that sends a notification on an incoming webhook teams. However, the answer I receive is "Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook". I do not understand why it does not work.

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "2m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "simple": {
      "summary": "Test Nom",
      "text": "test"
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "always": {}
  },
  "actions": {
    "MS_TEAMS_PORT443": {
      "webhook": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "outlook.office.com",
        "port": 443,
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/webhook/XYZ",
        "params": {},
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{{#toJson}}ctx.payload.summary{{/toJson}}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the response when I launch it:

```
{
  "watch_id": "_inlined_",
  "node": "QUApyNq4S5GyhHF-CuNjfg",
  "state": "executed",
  "status": {
    "state": {
      "active": true,
      "timestamp": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z"
    },
    "last_checked": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z",
    "last_met_condition": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z",
    "actions": {
      "MS_TEAMS_PORT443": {
        "ack": {
          "timestamp": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z",
          "state": "awaits_successful_execution"
        },
        "last_execution": {
          "timestamp": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z",
          "successful": false,
          "reason": "received [400] status code"
        }
      }
    },
    "execution_state": "executed",
    "version": -1
  },
  "trigger_event": {
    "type": "manual",
    "triggered_time": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z",
    "manual": {
      "schedule": {
        "scheduled_time": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "simple": {
      "summary": "Test Nom",
      "text": "test"
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "always": {}
  },
  "metadata": {
    "name": "testJsonALaMano",
    "xpack": {
      "type": "json"
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "execution_time": "2019-10-21T08:40:39.802Z",
    "execution_duration": 125,
    "input": {
      "type": "simple",
      "status": "success",
      "payload": {
        "summary": "Test Nom",
        "text": "test"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "type": "always",
      "status": "success",
      "met": true
    },
    "actions": [
      {
        "id": "MS_TEAMS_PORT443",
        "type": "webhook",
        "status": "failure",
        "reason": "received [400] status code",
        "webhook": {
          "request": {
            "host": "outlook.office.com",
            "port": 443,
            "scheme": "https",
            "method": "post",
            "path": "/webhook/XYZ",
            "headers": {
              "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": "Test Nom"
          },
          "response": {
            "status": 400,
            "headers": {
              "date": [
                "Mon, 21 Oct 2019 08:40:38 GMT"
              ],
              "content-length": [
                "49"
              ],
              "expires": [
                "-1"
              ],
              "x-beserver": [
                "VI1PR07MB5053"
              ],
              "x-aspnet-version": [
                "4.0.30319"
              ],
              "x-proxy-backendserverstatus": [
                "400"
              ],
              "x-cafeserver": [
                "VE1PR03CA0023.EURPRD03.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM"
              ],
              "x-calculatedbetarget": [
                "VI1PR07MB5053.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com"
              ],
              "request-id": [
                "6d651f70-74b5-4010-a2a6-662666fa9985"
              ],
              "pragma": [
                "no-cache"
              ],
              "x-msedge-ref": [
                "Ref A: C6E8A3DCFF9541DD95D63FD71ACD695C Ref B: PAR02EDGE0513 Ref C: 2019-10-21T08:40:39Z"
              ],
              "x-feserver": [
                "VE1PR03CA0023"
              ],
              "x-powered-by": [
                "ASP.NET"
              ],
              "x-backendhttpstatus": [
                "400"
              ],
              "content-type": [
                "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
              ],
              "cache-control": [
                "no-cache"
              ]
            },
            "body": "Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "messages": []
}
```

Comment: The issue is, putting the values in the body. The "Body" field is a string and you can't use json in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761522/watcher-job-created-in-elastic-search-to-push-alerts-to-promotheus-alert-manager Did you find an answer? please share

Answer (score 0):

Wrong body statement. Need to send text in body. Change your body to be like this

```
"body": "{\"text\": \"{{ctx.payload.summary}}\"}"
```

Comment: Worked for me working on 7.14.1 ES & Kibana

Answer (score 0):

`source` property is your friend here:

```
"body": {
      "source": {
        "text" : "Test Nom"
      }
 }
```

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link for documentation of this? I couldn't find it referenced here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/actions-webhook.html it just says `body` is a string

Comment: As far as I remember this schema is for Teams and not coming from Elastic.